# HttpWebRequest 429 error, any way to bypass?

Tags: c#, json, httpwebrequest, httpwebresponse, http-status-code-429

I need to read information based on tax identification using json from 
https://wl-api.mf.gov.pl/api/search/nip/5250007738?date=2020-02-13

And there is working code example

```
 private static void Main()
        {
            ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = true;
            ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;

            Log("NIP: ");
            string nip = Console.ReadLine();

            string date = DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString();
            string url = "https://wl-api.mf.gov.pl/api/search/nip/{0}?date={1}";
            string fullUrl = string.Format(url, nip, date);

            var get = Get(fullUrl);

            RootObject account = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(get);
            if (account != null)
                Log("Status: " + account.result.subject.statusVat);

            Log("Press any key to continue...");


            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        public static string Get(string url)
        {
            try
            {
                HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
                request.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip | DecompressionMethods.Deflate;

                using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
                using (Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream())
                using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))
                {
                    return reader.ReadToEnd();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception err)
            {
                Log(err.Message);
            }
            return string.Empty;
        }

        static void Log(string msg)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(msg);
        }
```

But there are some limits on API which allows me to get only 10 requests/day. However, using web browser I can get it without any limits. Is there any way to bypass 429 limit?

Answer (score 0):

You could bypass this limit by spoofing your IP or your User-agent, but you really shouldn't.

If the server's API limit is 10 requests per day, you should respect this limit. If this was your server, sure, you could bypass it. However, since it's not your server/API, please abide by its rules.

More info on 429 error: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/429

Comment: Well, it is not really like I want to "ping" it 10xsec, just one day I might need to use it 5 times, another 15 times. By the way, why there is no limits when I visit site? I can refresh it holding F5 down and still getting correct response.

Comment: This is because you're accessing the website with the web browser using the HTTP protocol, and not an API. Meanwhile, your code uses the website's API, which may limit usage. Hope this clarifies it.